# OL3 parser flips the coordinates

Tags: mapserver, openlayers

When requesting featureInfo from MapServer using getGetFeatureInfoUrl() of OL3 lib

```
var req_url = the_layer.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
  evt.coordinate,
  map.getView().getResolution(),
  map.getView().getProjection(), //4326
  {
     'INFO_FORMAT': 'application/vnd.ogc.gml',
  }
);
```

it returns response in which the coordinates X and Y are in coorect order but after parsing the response theu are flipped:

```
$.ajax(req_url, {
            async: false
          })
          .done(function(resp){
            //console.log(resp);
            WMSfeatures = parser.readFeatures(resp);
            console.log(WMSfeatures);
           });
```

Coordinates in response from mapserver:

`[[223.745,250.638],[232.028,255.22],[229.376,264.126]]` (in EPSG:4326)

Parsed response:

`[[250.638,223.745],[255.22,232.028],[264.126,229.376]]` (in EPSG:4326)

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If you ever need to flip coordinates.. one way is to send it to postgis, that have a function for it:

```
//prepare GeoJson parser
var parser_GJ = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
//prepare GeoJson String
var GJ_geom_str = parser_GJ.writeGeometry(WMSfeatures[0].getGeometry()); 
//Send to PHP function using AJAX (returns GeoJSON String)
var GJ_geom = Utils.flipCoordinates(GJ_geom_str);
//Set geometry for the feature
WMSfeatures[0].setGeometry(parser_GJ.readGeometry(GJ_geom));
```

The PHP snippet is following:

```
function flip_coordinates($GJ_geom){
  $sql = "SELECT ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_FlipCoordinates(ST_Force_2D(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('$GJ_geom')))) as flipped";
  return dibi::fetchSingle($sql);
}
```